# Integrating keycloak with spring cloud gateway with multiple clients

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a two microservices(powered by spring boot) running. Each of which is secured with oauth2. And I am using keycloak as the provider. Both these services use different flows.
Service1 uses Direct Grant Access flow(Resource owner password grant) and Service2 uses Standard flow(Authorization Code grant).

So when the user calls an endpoint on Service1, it should have the bearer token with it and when the user calls Service2, user will be redirected to the keycloak login page.

I want to separate this logic from both the microservices and put it in spring cloud gateway.

I have the routing part setup but I am not able to figure out how to configure the security part.

I have something like this

```
 spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            token-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            userinfo-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
        registration:
          keycloak-with-password-flow:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: Service1
            client-secret: 2cff54cf-f29e-4f0a-905d-33dd12186dc2
            authorization-grant-type: password
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak"
          keycloak-without-authcode-scope:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: Service2
            client-secret: 2c13020a-3e3f-40f3-837f-165f8a0c027a
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak"
```

With this setting, when I call an endpoint on Service1 with the bearer token, I am being redirected to login page.

Could someone let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: Nope. I could not figure out this. So I had to move one of the microservice out of cloud gateway